# How to reuse Tensorflow operations created in loop

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a method that creates several optimizers in a loop. This method is called several times, and I don't want to recreate theses optimizers each time the method is called. Is there a way to get the previously created optimizers so that I don't have to create new ones?

```
def trainWordEmbeddings(self, sent_words, sent_num, window_size):
        for j in range(len(sent_words)):
            pos_context = self.getPosContext(sent_words, j, window_size)
            neg_context = self.neg_contexts.getNegContext(j, sent_num, pos_context)
            word_obj = self.objective.objective(WORD, sent_words[j], pos_context, neg_context)
            opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.eta).minimize(word_obj)
            self.session.run(opt)
```

Comment: Please explain why you need to call the method multiple times. If you have different inputs each time, try using placeholders to define the ops instead of repeatedly calling the method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've made `word_obj` and `opt` into private variables that use placeholders to take inputs. I have another method that uses the same kind of logic that takes in a tensor that needs to be dynamically built in the loop. I need to call this method and the other method for each sentence in my training set. I will update my question shortly.